# how can I convert a PyDateTime Object to PyString Object in python c api?

Tags: python

I want to get the string value of a PyDateTime object in c.

But I can't find any api to do this.

Can anybody help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem.

What I need to do is convert the PyDateTime object to PyString using PyString_FromFormat.